# How specify Ajax jquery url path if all codes in one file

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have issue with specifying the Ajax jQuery url path. I have one function  contains all Html markup codes, php sned mail codes and Ajax jQuery code as follow

How i can specify `url` property in ajax code?

**Info:** i use wordpress theme and this function within my plugin directory

```
<?php
    function bsncontact() {

        //All php codes here
?>
        <form id="ajax-contact" class="navbar-form" action="" method="POST">
            <!-- other html markup codes -->
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function(){
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '',
                data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&subject=" + subject + "&message=" + message,
                success: function(text) {

                }
           });
           });
       </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking to do.  Are you trying to post back to the same url that served the page?

Comment: i have that function i create it for sending email it is work perfectly. when i call the function in any place within my wordpress theme show contact form and send email without any problem and i add the ajax codes until don't refresh page during send email but i don't know how i specify the `url` property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say use wordpress theme. In wordpress theme this is very easy you can register ajax within your wordpress in backend(admin panel) and in front end of your theme

**First** you may put your ajax code in separate (for example put ajax code within `myajax.js` file) and then put it within your `js` folder, and register the your ajax code (you create function and register these scripts within it) and wordpress admin ajax over your theme by using `wp_localize_scrip`

```
function my_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', plugins_url( '/js/myajax.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object',array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'we_value' => 1234 ) );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

**Second** put your `HTML` form code within separate function for example

```
<?php
    function myhtmlfunc() {
        //Your html contact form here
        //not important if form contain action="", you can remove it
    }
?>
```

Until now very easy.

**Third** put your `php` sent mail code within another function and Ajax on the Viewer-Facing Side for bot logged and visitor users abs below
[AJAX in Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

```
<?php
    function myphpmail() {
        //Put all php codes here
    }
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'myphpmail' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'myphpmail' );
?>
```

Fourth then set your `ajax` url as below

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:ajax_object.ajaxurl,
    success: function() {}
});
```

Comment: thank you this is work with me and perfect way because i can don't use ful url

Answer (score 2):

In wordpress you have to create hook firstly.

To create hook we use **add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );**

**my_action_callback** is a function that will called when "wp_ajax_my_action" action is called.

I have updated your code 
Try this:

```
<?php
        add_action( 'wp_bsncontact', 'bsncontact' );
        function bsncontact() {
            //All php codes here
    ?>
            <form id="ajax-contact" class="navbar-form" action="" method="POST">
                <!-- other html markup codes -->
            </form>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(function(){
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://abcd.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
                    data: "action=wp_bsncontact&name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&subject=" + subject + "&message=" + message,
                    success: function(text) {

                    }
               });
               });
           </script>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

To call hook you need to pass "action" in data of your ajax as shown in above code.

Please modify this code as per your requirement.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: thank you this is helpful way but i want don't put full url because it is not successful or good way

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you want to achieve,

Try using `"<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` in the url of your ajax code.

PHP_SELF is a variable that returns the current script being executed.